# How to remove left panel from Category page Magento?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I want to remove the right panel from my category page. In fact I could do it manually while creating a category and select 2 page layout there. But Since I have a long list of categories And I Dont Need the right panel anyway. So i would like to remove it permanently from my category page. Is there any simple way using Xml or Phtml I can Achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Your catalog.xml file

Find `<catalog_category_default translate="label">` Tag Around Line number 76

JUst go to the above xml tag and then add this code it will set the default template to 1columt

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Event better: use local.xml in your custom layout.